# Wrong variable number being passed through

Tags: javascript

When this initially loads employmentJobs displays as employmentJobs1 in the console which is what I want. Once I clicked on the button which has the .employmentJobs1 .addDuty class it should log out employmentJobs1 again but instead it logs out employmentJobs2.

Could anyone provide any guidance?

```
for (var q = 1; q <= 1; q++){
   console.log('employmentJobs'+q); 

    $('.employmentJobs'+q +' .addDuty').click(function(){

        console.log('employmentJobs'+q); 
        countDuties++;
        $('.employmentJobs'+q +' .mainDuties').clone().attr('class', 'form-group mainDutyOrder mainDuties'+ countDuties).insertAfter('.employmentJobs'+q +' .mainDutyOrder:last');

        return false;

    }); 

  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting a click handler within a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function in your click event handler executes at a far later time, meaning that the loop has finished (and the value of `q` as a result is the final value of the loop in every click event). Simply close over the value of `q` using an IIFE to create a new execution context.

```
for (var q = 1; q <= 1; q++){

   //close over q
   (function(q){

   console.log('employmentJobs'+q); 

    $('.employmentJobs'+q +' .addDuty').click(function(){

        console.log('employmentJobs'+q); 
        countDuties++;
        $('.employmentJobs'+q +' .mainDuties').clone().attr('class', 'form-group mainDutyOrder mainDuties'+ countDuties).insertAfter('.employmentJobs'+q +' .mainDutyOrder:last');

        return false;

    }); 

  //pass q in to close over its value
  })(q)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact, that you should NOT put event bindings in loops, your problem tackles "encapsulation".

JavaScript uses a so called function scope. But what you need is a block scope(i.e. c#).

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) you can find an exact description of this kind of problem and there are even examples that exactly fit your needs.

But what you could instead also do is: put your elemets in containers, and bind a click dynamically on them like:

```
$('body).on('click', '.yourWrapperElement > .clickableElements', function() {
    //cour cloning magic here
});
```

this makes all children inside .element clickable, even if they're added after the document is loaded